# Messenger cannot connect to a XMPP server from the first attempt

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

I wrote 2 functions:

```
if let stream = xmppStream {
        if stream.isAuthenticated(){
            println("Logged In")
        } else {
            println("something is wrong")
        }
}


func xmppStreamDidConnect(sender: XMPPStream) {
    println("xmppStreamDidConnect")
    isOpen = true
    var error: NSError?
    if (xmppStream!.authenticateWithPassword(password.text, error: &error) ) {
        println("authentification successful")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToBuddyList", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

And when I run my app it prints in the terminal:

```
something is wrong
xmppStreamDidConnect
authentification successful
```

Even if I putted true credentials it prints at first [something is wrong] and just later [authentification successful]. Why it happens?

I want alert users just in case of [something is wrong], not in [successful] case, but it alert it in successful case, too.

Answer (score 2):

Implement **xmppStreamDidAuthenticate** and **didNotAuthenticate** methods of **XMPPStreamDelegate** .

After calling **authenticateWithPassword**  client authentication  will surely end up in above two function (xmppStreamDidAuthenticate and didNotAuthenticate) until then **stream.isAuthenticated()** will return “0”.